# SQL Stored Procedure WHERE.. IN clause multiple VALUE data

Tags: sql, subquery

I am new to SQL stored procedures. I need help creating query that can pull information from one table connecting to other table.

Table_Class:

```
Code    Class
-------------
002     Geometry
045     Health
074     Algebra
415     Social Study
```

Table_Student

```
ID    Student    Class_Code
---------------------------
01    Nancy       002,074
02    Mark        415
```

How do I show result for Nancy's class:

```
Geometry
Algebra
```

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Class
WHERE Code IN (SELECT Class_Code FROM Table_Student WHERE ID = '01')
```

But the result is blank/no data.

Look forward for any advice. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble! (One row per class/student is the SQL way. I.e. create another table for attended classes.)

Comment: Fix your database structure.

Comment: There's no column `Code` in your table `Table_Student`.  I'm surprise it gives you blank instead of error.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a cloumn from another table you should have foreign keys, in order for you to use those you cant be storing multiple keys in one column, so basically what you want to have is something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[students]([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,[name] TEXT NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[class]([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,[name] TEXT NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[studentclass]([studentId] INTEGER NOT NULL,[classId] INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY(studentId) REFERENCES students(id),FOREIGN KEY(classId) REFERENCES class(id))
```

Then you can query

```
SELECT * FROM class WHERE CODE IN(SELECT classId FROM studentclass WHERE studentId = 1)
```

IN SQL if you see that the relation between 2 tables is multiple on both sides, you need another table, in this case, a student sees multiple classes, but a class is also seen by multiple students, so you create the table studentClass

Answer (score 0):

**The Best Way:**
 Restructure your database in such a manner that pulling the given info in more condusive to querying, particularly the query you are trying to perform

Table_Class:

```
Code    Class
-------------
002   Geometry
045   Health
074   Algebra
415   Social Study
```

Table_Student

```
ID    Student    Class_Code
---------------------------
01    Nancy       002,074
02    Mark        415
```

Table_Student_Class:

```
ID    studentId    classId
--------------------------
01    01           002
02    01           074
03    02           415
```

Then your query would simply be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Class
WHERE Code IN (SELECT classId FROM Table_Student_Class WHERE studentId = '01')
```

**The Hacky Way:** 
If you are in a situation such that you can't alter you database, you can do the following, thought it will act far less efficient

```
SELECT Class
FROM Table_Class
WHERE Code IN (
    SELECT value  
    FROM Table_Student CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Class_Code, ',')
    WHERE ID = '01'
)
```